# Tornado '@run_on_executor' is blocking

Tags: python, tornado, nonblocking

I would like to ask how [tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor](https://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor) (later just `run_on_executor`) works, because 
I probably do not understand how to run synchronous task to not block the main IOLoop.

All the examples using `run_on_executor`, which I found, are using just `time` to block the loop.
With `time` module it works fine, but when I try some time intesive calculations, using `run_on_executor`, the task blocks the IOLoop.
I am able to see that the app uses multiple threads, but it is still blocking.

I want to use `run_on_executor` for hashing passwords using `bcrypt`, but replaced it with this calculation to gain some extra time for testing.

Here I have small app, to demonstrate my confusion.

```
from tornado.options import define, options
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
from tornado import gen
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
import tornado.httpclient
import tornado.escape
import time
import concurrent.futures
import urllib


executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(20)
define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)


# Should not be blocking ?
class ExpHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    _thread_pool = executor

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, num):
        i = int(num)
        result = yield self.exp(2, i)
        self.write(str(result))
        self.finish()

    @run_on_executor(executor="_thread_pool")
    def exp(self, x, y):
        result = x ** y
        return(result)


class NonblockingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        try:
            response = yield http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/")
            self.write(response.body)
        except tornado.httpclient.HTTPError as e:
            self.write(("Error: " + str(e)))
        finally:
            http_client.close()
        self.finish()


class SleepHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    _thread_pool = executor

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, sec):
        sec = float(sec)
        start = time.time()
        res = yield self.sleep(sec)
        self.write("Sleeped for {} s".format((time.time() - start)))
        self.finish()

    @run_on_executor(executor="_thread_pool")
    def sleep(self, sec):
        time.sleep(sec)
        return(sec)


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/exp/(?P<num>[^\/]+)?', ExpHandler),
            (r'/nonblocking/?', NonblockingHandler),
            (r'/sleep/(?P<sec>[^\/]+)?',SleepHandler)
        ]
        settings = dict(
            debug=True,
            logging="debug"
        )
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


def  main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    io_loop.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would be very grateful for any explanation why `ExpHandler`, running in `executor` is blocking the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python (at least in the CPython implementation) has a Global Interpreter Lock which prevents multiple threads from executing Python code at the same time. In particular, anything which runs in a single Python opcode is uninterruptible unless it calls a C function which explicitly releases the GIL. A large exponentation with `**` holds the GIL the whole time and thus blocks all other python threads, while a call to `bcrypt()` will release the GIL so other threads can continue to work.

Comment: I have read about GIL, but obviosly did not understand the concept well enough, but now I see it more clearly. 
Also did not realized bcrypt is implemented in 'C', with GIL releasing functionality.
So next time if I will need to implement some computationally intensive task, I will use some library intended for that kind of purpose. 
I also tried to implement **(pow) through simple multiplication generator function, it is not very efficient, but at least it is not blocking. Very nice (:

Thank you very much for clarification.