# Tornado error: cannot switch to a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

A request comes to tornado's GET handler of a web app.
From the `GET` function, a `blocking_task` function is called. This `blocking_task` function has `@run_on_executor` decorator.

But this execution fails.
Could you please help on this. It seems that motor db is not able to execute the thread.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado import gen, web
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import argparse
from common.config import APIConfig
import sys
import os
import motor

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--config-file", dest='config_file',
                    help="Config file location")
args = parser.parse_args()
CONF = APIConfig().parse(args.config_file)

client = motor.MotorClient(CONF.mongo_url)
db = client[CONF.mongo_dbname]
class Handler(web.RequestHandler):

    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

    def initialize(self):
        """ Prepares the database for the entire class """
        self.db = self.settings["db"]

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.blocking_task()

    @run_on_executor
    def blocking_task(self):
        mongo_dict = self.db.test_cases.find_one({"name": "Ping"})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application([
        (r"/", Handler),
    ],
        db=db,
        debug=CONF.api_debug_on,
    )
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().start()




> ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <functools.partial
> object at 0x7f72dfbe48e8> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/ioloop.py",
> line 600, in _run_callback
>     ret = callback()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/stack_context.py",
> line 275, in null_wrapper
>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/motor-0.5-py2.7.egg/motor/frameworks/tornado.py",
> line 231, in callback
>     child_gr.switch(future.result()) error: cannot switch to a different thread
```

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally following code works,  Thank you @kwarunek 
Also added parameters to the callback function.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado import gen, web
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import argparse
from common.config import APIConfig
import sys
import os
import motor

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--config-file", dest='config_file',
                    help="Config file location")
args = parser.parse_args()
CONF = APIConfig().parse(args.config_file)

client = motor.MotorClient(CONF.mongo_url)
db = client[CONF.mongo_dbname]

class Handler(web.RequestHandler):

    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

    def initialize(self):
        """ Prepares the database for the entire class """
        self.db = self.settings["db"]

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.blocking_task("Ping", "Void-R")


    @run_on_executor
    def blocking_task(self, name, status):
        IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=lambda: self.some_update(name, status))

    @gen.coroutine
    def some_update(self, name, status):
        mongo_dict = yield self.db.test_cases.find_one({"name": name})
        self.db.test_cases.update({ "name": name }, { "$set": { "status" : status } } )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application([
        (r"/", Handler),
    ],
        db=db,
        debug=CONF.api_debug_on,
    )
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: `find_one` should be yielded according to docs https://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial-tornado.html#updating-documents

Comment: also `self` is missing

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor)

> IOLoop and executor to be used are determined by the io_loop and
>   executor attributes of self. To use different attributes, pass keyword
>   arguments to the decorator

You have to provide a init threadpoolexecutor:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado import gen, web
from tornado.concurrent import run_on_executor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


class Handler(web.RequestHandler):

    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.blocking_task()

    @run_on_executor
    def blocking_task(self):
        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application([
        (r"/", Handler),
    ])
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

By default `run_on_executor` search for threadpool in `executor` attribute, unless you pass other explicitly, e.g.

```
_thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

@run_on_executor(executor='_thread_pool')
def blocking_task(self):
    pass
```

**edit**

Basically IOLoop should be used in single-threaded env (you can run separate IOLoop on each thread, but it is not your case). To communicate with IOLoop you should use [add_callback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback), that is the only thread safe function.

You can use like:

```
@run_on_executor
def blocking_task(self):
    IOLoop.instance().add_callback(some_update)

@gen.coroutine
def some_update():
    db.test_cases.update({ "name": "abc" }, { "$set": { "status" : "xyz" } } )
```

But do you really need threading at all. What is the purpose of the separate thread if you schedule update on main - IOLoop's thread.

Comment: As side note, keep in mind that it might block - descriptive @Ben answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841455/tornado-run-on-executor-is-blocking

Comment: I am facing issue from the motor db package.
If I don't execute self.db.test_cases.update, then executor works fine. 
The problem is with the call of motor db calls. 
Motro pacakage is not allowing to execute

Comment: This is my first post in stack overflow. Please ignore my mistakes.
I have executed as per your suggestions, not the following one does not work at all .. i did not got the print statment value i have kept in some updates function

Answer (score 0):

Motor is a non-blocking library, designed to be used from the single `IOLoop` thread. You would use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a blocking library like PyMongo, but you must not use other threads with Motor.

Instead, you should call the Motor methods with `yield` directly:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    yield self.non_blocking_task()

@gen.coroutine
def non_blocking_task(self):
    motor_dict = yield self.db.test_cases.find_one({"name": "Ping"})
```

Also note that if you do use `@run_on_executor` with a blocking library like PyMongo, the decorator makes blocking functions non-blocking, so the decorated function must be called with `yield`.